# How to extract rows of a matrix with condition in matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose

```
  A =  1  0  0
       1  0  1
       0  0  1
       1  0  1
       0  0  0
```

Now I want to extract rows whose 1st and 3rd column values are 1 at the same row
ie
  output should be

```
    1  0  1
    1  0  1
```

tried with  `A(A(1:end,1)==A(1:end,3)==1)`, but not getting result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
A(A(:,1) == 1 & A(:,3) == 1, :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better example -

```
A = [
    1  1  0
    1  0  1
    0  0  1
    1  0  1
    0  0  0]
```

You can achieve your result using [**`ismember`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) -

```
out = A(ismember(A(:,[1 3]),[1  1],'rows'),:)
```

Output -

```
out =

     1     1     1
     1     0     1
     1     0     1
```

**Extended Part:** If you want to extend this to a bigger case, let's say a case with `A` as 10x10 and you would like to extract all rows with `ones` on 1, 3, 6, 8 and 9 column numbers, so just do this -

```
out = A(ismember(A(:,[1 3 6 8 9]),ones(1,5),'rows'),:)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that `A` is logical, or will only contain 0's and 1's, then

```
A(A(:,3) & A(:,1), :)
```

otherwise, you need an explicit comparison to 1, so then go with Rafael's solution.

The reason why *chaining* doesn't work (your initial attempt) is the following. Consider the first part:

```
>> ( A(1:end,1)==A(1:end,3) )
ans =
     0
     1
     0
     1
     1
```

Comparing this to `1` will obviously give the same result:

```
>> ( A(1:end,1)==A(1:end,3) ) == 1
ans =
     0
     1
     0
     1
     1
```

e.g., you're not comparing the *values* to 1, but comparing the result of the *comparison* to 1. Note that order is irrelevant:

```
>> 1 == A(1:end,1) == A(1:end,3) 
ans =
     0
     1
     0
     1
     1

>> A(1:end,1) == 1 == A(1:end,3) 
ans =
     0
     1
     0
     1
     1
```